# Encrypting php-sql user data and structure

Tags: php, encryption

I'm working on a online platform that processes financial data and i'm looking to encrypt all data on it, to avoid leaking the information in any way other than the person giving out his personal password. I hope you can help me with this following:

The platform interacts between a php file and a mysql database. A user personal key is defined by a session_id, given after login.

Table 1: **Users** (user_id, email, password, etc) - this stores the relevant data for any user to logon to our platform and access any of our templates.

Table 2: **User_template1_data** (template_user_id, user_id, email, name, specific info.)  this stores the specific data to the data template

Table 3,4,5,6: **logs** (log_id, date time, details, template_user_id etc.).

In the **log** tables (which could be, *payments, jobs, 'expanses'*, etc) we store the sensitive data, that nobody else than the user may read, not even the admins, unless given access to it.

Now the way I had it in mind was following:

**Example:**

**Table 1:**

```
user_id - Name - email - pass
1 - Jay - jay.. - (salt / hashed)
```

**Table 2:**

```
User_template1_data, user_id, division * 
1 - 1 - Jay - jay.. - accountant
```

The php will see that user 1 obviously is an accountant. Which is not really sensitive data.

How ever in **Table 3** we add the following data:

```
> log_id - User_template1_data - date - client - earnings 1 - 1 -
> 2016,01,01 - Gucci SLR - 5000,00 2 - 1 - 2016,02,01 - Prada SLR -
> 51000,00 3 - 1 - 2016,03,01 - Chanel SLR - 15000,00
```

This connection should be encrypted, so nobody who hacks into the database can see the connections. I was thinking of the following, please correct me if i'm wrong:

```
> log_id - User_template1_data - date - client - earnings 1 - hash and
> salt the User_template1_data - 2016-01-01 - Gucci SLR - 5000 2 - hash
> and salt the User_template1_data - 2016-02,01 - Prada SLR - 51000 3 -
> hash and salt the User_template1_data - 2016-03-01 - Chanel SLR -
> 15000
```

This way only the person who is logged in, stores the sensitive data encrpyted, it will not have be be decrypted then.

**I AM A ROOKIE TO ENCRYPTING SO PLEASE ADVISE ME IF I'M WRONG**
Most importantly, which encryption should i use, how should i build it up etc. Much appreciated!

Comment: I'm a little confused. What part are you exactly wanting to be encrypted? All data stored in the database? For safe connections themselves you'll need SSL but as for the data im lost.

Comment: Luckily I happen to have [this post](https://paragonie.com/white-paper/2015-secure-php-data-encryption#index-encrypted-information) open right now, so give it a read.

Comment: If you are dealing with Financial data / transactions then stop doing it yourself and use an established secured system. ***DON'T*** roll your own.

Comment: @Martin Got any suggestions for an established secured system? Do you mean a full functioning platform or a database-process function? The point is that my system is unique and not excisting. We're not dealing with transactions etc, we are just dealing with administrative data. So it's general information, just a higher risk value.

Comment: @Matt i'm mainly trying to secure our data to any hack-attempts. My main idea was to encrpyt the data in the database, so that if somebody manages to break in the database nobody besides the user can read the content. Might you have any other suggestions that would work better, feel free to advise. I'm very new to data-security.

Comment: Does your data fall under the remit of the PCI DSS ?

Comment: At the end of the day if you are encrypting the data you'll have to store a salt to decrypt the data. If someone gains access to the database they will have access to the means of decrypting the data which means encryption will only slow them down unless you store these elsewhere but it will become crazy complex as data enlarges.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should set up the database so it can be trusted to be safe, but it could be a fun experiment to solve this. The most important part is using standard encrypt methods in your programming language, in case of php go for the openssl package.

Hash with salt will not help much here, since hashing is a one way operation so not even the user owning the data will be able to decrypt it.

I would have gone for something like

- Use an encryption key which you store encrypted with the users password that you decrypt and put in session when the user log in. Of course make sure sessions are encrypted on the disc and that you store the password using bcrypt, but encrypt the key using the clear text password so that the encryption key cannot be found.
- When storing sensitive data encrypt it using the key in session and when getting the data decrypt it using the same key
- Remember to update the stored encrypted key when the user change password

I suggest using AES-256-CBC for encryption.

If this is going to be used for something more than experimenting or learning I suggest first to search for existing solutions for this.

Also remember if the user forgets the password it will be no way of getting the data back

Comment: Thanks @rypskar! it makes a lot of sense to me the way you describe it! Now the only problems would be: indeed, what if a person losses the password. And the second, how is it possible to store a encryption key into a password, is there a specific ready2use function for?

Comment: If the person looses the password his data is lost, which is why you should look for existing software for this if it is something you want to use in production. To store the encryption key you need a separate column in the database you can encrypt it using `openssl_encrypt($data, AES-256-CBC, $password)` and use openssl_decrypt in the same way to decrypt it.  Again a warning to anyone wanting to try this, creating your own security layer is a good way for learning and understanding security, but for production the best is always to use existing software that is tested by security experts